# C++ stream second insertion operator

Tags: c++, stream, operator-keyword, insertion

Is it possible to define a second insertion operator to have two modes of outputting a class? Say e.g. one that outputs all members and one that just outputs some basic unique identifier that is grep-able in a log? If so, is there an operator that is usually chosen? I would guess as analogy to `<<` one might use `<<<` if that is legal?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to output only the id, then the best idea is probably to provide a method to get the id in a type that's streamable (e.g. `std::string id() const;`).  That's much more intuitive to other people working on the code than some strange operator use.

Your suggestion of `<<<` (it's not possible to create new operators in C++, but ignoring that for a moment) reveals that you're happy for there to be different code at the point of call.  Therefore, the only benefit you'd get would be the saving of a few character's source code; it isn't worth the obfuscation.

By way of contrast, there are situations where you want the same streaming notation to invoke different behaviours, such as switching between id-only and full data, or different representations such as tag/value, CSV, XML, and binary.  These alternatives are usually best communicated by either:

- using different stream types (e.g. XMLStream rather than `std::ostream`), and defining `XMLStream& operator<<(XMLStream&, const My_Type&)` etc, and/or
- using stream manipulators - you can create your own - random Google result: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=171014&seqNum=2

Comment: Really like this answer, especially the possibility of using different streams! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's ***no*** such thing already defined or in use by convention.

Also, you cannot define your own operators in C++, you have to use one of the ones already in the language and overloadable, and ***`<<<` isn't an operator*** in C++, so it is out anyway.

I'd strongly recommend you ***don't use some other operator*** for this. (See [rule #1 here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421708#4421708) for a more thorough explanation.) If you have subtle differences between output operations, ***well-chosen functions names*** go a long way for making better code than unclear operators arbitrarily picked.

Answer (score 2):

No. You can't define your own operators (`<<<` doesn't exist in C++). But you can define a `id()` method returning a string and output this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such operator as `<<<` in C++.

You are, however, free to implement, for example `operator <(ostream&,Object&)`, which would do what you want. The problem is, code may get unreadable when you try to chain `<` and `<<` together.

Comment: While this is technically true, you can do it, other developers and yourself down the road will appreciate if when overloading operators you use some *sane* semantics. A few months from now you might start wondering how can an `ostream` be smaller than your `object`

Comment: Well, true. But if he really wants to have another operator for this purpose - that is how it can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `operator |` for instance. Another way of doing this is to define small tag classes for which the operator is overloaded; example (pretty simplistic but you get the point):

```
template< class T >
struct GrepTag
{
  GrepTag( const T& );
  T value;
}

template< class T >
Greptag< T > MakeGrepTag( const T& x )
{
  return GrepTag< T >( x ); 
}

template< class T >
MyClass& MyClass::operator << ( const GrepTag< T >& g )
{
  //output g.value here
}

MyClass() << MakeGrepTag( "text" );
```

Yet another way, more like the standard streams, is to use a tag as well but keep some state internally:

```
struct GrepTag
{
}

MyClass& MyClass::operator << ( const GrepTag& g )
{
  grepState = true;
}

template< class T >
MyClass& MyClass::operator << ( const T& )
{
  if( grepState )
  {
    //output special
    grepState = false;
  }
  else
  {
    //output normal
  }        
}

MyClass() << GrepTag() << "text";
```

Comment: @Alexandre: I removed some typos now; what exactly are you referring to? I'm not showing full class definitions so it won't compile, I know that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define your own operators in C++. You can only overload those that exist.

So I recomend not using an operator for outputting basic unique identifier grep-able in a log. This doesn't correspond to any existing operator role. Use a method instead, such as `exportToLog()`.